# Data loss while converting from jpeg to BGRA using ffmpeg

Tags: image-processing, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert a JPG Frame into RGBA frame using ffmpeg. The original image size is 250x250 with pixel format AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P. The source line stride array contains [256, 128, 128] (for 3 planes). My destination frame size is 250x250. Following is the code.

```
AVFrame* GetBGRAFrame(AVFrame* pFrame)
{       
    const int kiImageWidth = pFrame->width ;
    const int kiImageHeight = pFrame->height ;

    int iDestWidth = kiImageWidth;
    int iDestHeight = kiImageHeight;

    AVPixelFormat enPixelFormat = (AVPixelFormat)pFrame->format ;

    SwsContext* pImageConvertContext =
        sws_getContext(kiImageWidth, kiImageHeight, enPixelFormat, 
        iDestWidth, iDestHeight, PIX_FMT_BGRA, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    // Allocate destination frame
    int iNumBytes = avpicture_get_size(AV_PIX_FMT_BGRA, iDestWidth, iDestHeight);
    AVFrame* pFrame2 = av_frame_alloc();
    uint8_t* pFrameBuffer = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(iNumBytes * sizeof(uint8_t));       
    avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)pFrame2, pFrameBuffer, AV_PIX_FMT_BGRA, iDestWidth, iDestHeight);

    sws_scale(pImageConvertContext, pFrame->data, pFrame->linesize, 0, kiImageHeight, pFrame2->data, pFrame2->linesize);
    sws_freeContext(pImageConvertContext);

    return pFrame2;
}
```

After converting, I'm getting 2 transparent columns at the right side of my  destination frame.

I am able to get the proper image if I use the command line tool: 
ffmpeg -i image.jpg output.png

So, what is wrong with my code?

Is there any alignment requirement for the destination? If yes, how should I change my code to get 250x250 BGRA frame?

Thanks

Comment: what version of FFmpeg (or libswscale)?

Comment: Try passing `SWS_POINT` instead of `0` into the `sws_getContext`.

Comment: @Mark: I have tried SWS_POINT, SWS_AREA, SWS_BILINEAR, SWS_BICUBIC and SWS_LANCZOS. Still the issue persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're hitting [this](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=libswscale/x86/yuv2rgb_template.c;h=acb78f520e48a56b3878eeb2eb72082a39643015;hb=HEAD#l47) code in the yuv420p-to-RGB24 conversion:

```
h_size = (c->dstW + 7) & ~7;                                     \
if (h_size * depth > FFABS(dstStride[0]))                        \
    h_size -= 8;                                                 \
```

Since avpicture_get_size() should take care of all of that for you, I'd say this is a bug that you should report on trac.ffmpeg.org or the mailinglist...

[edit]
As a practical workaround, follow this comment from the [linked bug report](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1031#comment:7):

> Call instead av_image_alloc() directly [..] with an align parameter of 32.

Comment: I found that, it's a bug in FFmpeg. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1031#comment:7
A workaround is to turn off asm code using --disable-asm.

Comment: A better workaround is to follow this comment: "Call instead av_image_alloc() directly [..] with an align parameter of 32."

Comment: I could fix it by aligning my destination buffer to multiples of 8 explicitly.  av_image_alloc also seems to be working. I guess I would go with av_image_alloc. Thanks Ronald.